# Can I be tax-free for ten years as a non-habitual resident (NHR) in Portuguese territory?

Tags: taxes, portugal

My Portuguese is not very good, and the English versions of [this document](https://www.portaldascomunidades.mne.pt/images/GADG/IRS__Regime_Fiscal_Residente_N%C3%A3o_Habitual.pdf) have gone 404.  It seems to say that pensions from U.S. companies would not be taxed if they meet the requirements of foreign income in paragraph 1 of article 18 of the CIRS.  Unfortunately, the link to that paragraph is also 404.  And it does not say whether US Social Security is treated as a pension.

And, although this NHR is mentioned as available in lots of retirement or expat web pages, I have been told (by someone in Spain, not Portugal) that this 2009 program no longer exists.

My question (as stated in the title) is whether I could benefit by this if I obtain Portuguese residency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has not been abolished, [it’s part of the 2020 budget](https://home.kpmg/xx/en/home/insights/2020/04/flash-alert-2020-192.html). However, with regard to pensions specifically, it has been amended to tax pensions at 10%.